# adding UISearchBar in Navigation based application

Tags: iphone

I have added UISearch object on view in Navigation based application.

But when i run the application, only table view is visible, why UI Search object is not visible.

Thanks in advance,
iSight

Comment: the problem is not in UISearchBar. A simple UIButton would not show up in your application either. Check your addSubView, alloc/init methods, frames, etc.

Comment: @ahmet: I have added the said object on view(on Window) of MainWindow.xib. If i added to UIRootViewController.xib, it is visible at run time, but i cannot set the position to top.

Answer (score 0):

1)chech u made outlet of uisearch bar 
2)u connected delegate property to uisearchj bar
3)declared all essential method of uisearch bar for eg if u just made outlet of table view but didnt made its necessory methods then table will not show or work